# How to get list of files in repository in libgit/objective-git?

Tags: git, libgit2, objective-git

I want to get the list of files in a Git repository using [objective-git](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git), or [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/)

What I am doing now is calling the `git` command-line tool and parsing the output of `git ls-files` (or `git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD`, which gives the same results), e.g.

```
$ git ls-files
meta/LICENSE.md
.gitignore
README.md
```

I would rather use a direct API provided by libgit2. I have tried objective-git’s `-[GTTree enumerateContentsWithOptions:error:block:]` method, but the enumerated GTTreeEntry objects only provide a name and don’t know what subdirectory they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerateContentsWithOptions` takes a block with this signature:

```
typedef int(^GTTreeEnumerationBlock)(NSString *root, GTTreeEntry *entry);
```

`root` is the path to the directory that `entry` is in.